# HTML table: keep the same width for columns

Tags: html, css

I have a table with several groups of columns. The table is larger than my page, so I have a control to show/hide some of these groups to fit on the page. The initial table looks good: all columns are about the same width within a group. But when I hide a group, the columns are not the same width anymore, and it looks bad.

<s>Example: http://www.reviews-web-hosting.com/companies/apollohosting.html</s> (broken link)

So far, the table looks fine. Click on >>. The first column under "Ecommerce Pro" is much wider than the other columns under "Ecommerce Pro", it looks odd. Click on <<, this time the first column under "Value" is too wide. At least on Firefox.

I've tried to use

```
<colgroup><col /><col span="5" />...
```

but no luck. If I set a col to style="display: none", the set of columns is still displayed.

Any HTML/CSS tip to keep the columns with the same width withing a group?

**Edit:**

- to hide a column, I have to use visibility: collapse
- it seems to be resizing well now, I do not know why

Comment: The authentication dialog prevents me from using the site.

Comment: It only prevents me from seeing some images.

Comment: That's a wrong .htaccess that is asking to authenticate to get the images under /sites. I'll fix it tonight. I'm still working on building the site.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

If you set the style `table-layout: fixed;` on your table, you can override the browser's automatic column resizing. The browser will then set column widths based on the width of cells in the first row of the table. Change your `<thead>` to `<caption>` and remove the `<td>` inside of it, and then set fixed widths for the cells in `<tbody>`.

Comment: The single modification of adding `table-layout: fixed;` solved the same problem for me (FFox 11).

Comment: what's the point of using table layout fixed if you need to set cell width ?

Answer (score 31):

give this style to td: width: 1%;

Comment: With an unknown number of columns, this actually does the trick, if the table itself has a fixed width or `width: 100%`

Comment: Why does this work? And can I use this trick when I want to have the left column with a fixed width and all others with the same width?

Comment: @STh it works because the remaining width becomes equally distributed across all columns. As for having an additional fixed column, refer to @Ole Helgesen's answer and also use a `<colgroup>` definition in your table, which lets you specify a fixed width for any column.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, since you are only showing 3 columns:

```
Name    Value       Business
  or
Name    Business    Ecommerce Pro
```

why not set all 3 to have a width of 33.3%. since only 3 are ever shown at once, the browser *should* render them all a similar width.

Comment: The number of cells can cahnge as I hide/show different columns

Answer (score 0):

well, why don't you (get rid of sidebar and) squeeze the table so it is without show/hide effect? It looks odd to me now. The table is too robust.
Otherwise I think scunliffe's suggestion should do it. Or if you wish, you can just set the exact width of table and set either percentage or pixel width for table cells.

Comment: Some tables are way too large, event without the side bar.