# CSS for applying even width to dynamic number of table columns

Tags: css

I had a table which initially was to have two columns, both evenly sized at 50% width of the table.

This was accomplished with the following:

```
.catPagesTbl td {width: 50%;}
```

My needs with the table have changed as such that the table can have anywhere from 2 to many columns.

I still need to evenly space them, however many there are, and I don't want to include a style tag or css class in any of the  tags themselves.

Is there any way I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ideas here: [HTML table: keep the same width for columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570154/html-table-keep-the-same-width-for-columns).

Alternatively, if "many" is relatively small, you could define styles for each column layout:

```
table.twoCol td {
  width: 50%;
}
table.threeCol td {
  width: 33%;
}
table.fourCol td {
  width: 25%;
}
...
```

Then just include the appropriate class on the table.

Comment: Thanks - the "many" is relatively small so I just implemented your idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at using the datatables jQuery library -http://datatables.net/ 
It provides a number of ways to style the resulting table, such as styling per column. Levi Stanley's approach is also a good idea.