# How to make a table with equal column widths in CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a document containing a table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Word
        </td>
        <td>
            Definition
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Word
        </td>
        <td>
            Definition
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Word
        </td>
        <td>
            Definition
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Using CSS, I need to set all of the cells to 50% width, with text in the left "column" being right-aligned and text in the left column being left-aligned. I've tried many different options, e.g. `width: 50%; text-align: left`, but the results are always unusual. The results should look like this:

```
 _________________________
|       word | definition |
|____________|____________|
|       word | definition |
|____________|____________|
```

- I cannot adjust the table's actual code directly. I can only modify the CSS style.
- The answer in [Make columns of equal width in <table>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375288/make-columns-of-equal-width-in-table) is not suitable, because I do not know the width of the page, and that width might vary.

How can I set equal-width cells in a two-column table in CSS with everything aligned to the middle?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle with your attempts? Setting fixed widths and the text alignment on the cells should work

Comment: Use `table-layout: fixed;`

Comment: 50% width always works on cells, I'm guessing your problem is really with the table not being 100% in width.

Comment: Oh, I see. I had put padding on the outsides and between the cells. Also, some text that has really long words was pushing some tables to not be 50%/50%.

Answer (score 169):

You can set `table-layout: fixed;` on your table. Using this you can override the browser's automatic column resizing. Then column widths will be set based on the widths that you assign to the cells in the first row.

Comment: MDN link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

Answer (score 42):

I had the same issue in one of my projects, however it got fixed when I combined both the solutions above (Thanks to them). Here is my code snippet :

```
.Table{
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 31):

The table should have `width: 100%` property.
**[See example here](http://jsfiddle.net/rDa7k/1/)**

```
table{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

td{
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

About the text alignment you said two different things:

> Using CSS, I need to set all of the cells to 50% width, with text in
>   the left "column" being right-aligned and text in the left column
>   being left-aligned.

and then

> How can I set equal-width cells in a two-column table in CSS with everything aligned to the middle?

If the first is what you want and you cannot change your HTML you can use `td:first-child` to style your first column differently.

If the second is your best option, just change the `text-align` value to `center`.

Comment: What if I have a dynamic number of columns?

Comment: override this property and set it using javascript with the average when you are rendering them