# Resize the width of specific table cell without affecting others

Tags: css, html-table

I want the table column width stays at 50% but resize the highlighted row like in the picture without affecting others.

I use

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

[image]

**UPDATED**

I solved the problem by this.

```
table.border-outline tr:nth-child(2) .table-share-row-even:nth-child(2) .data-column{
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    right: -1px;
}
```

Comment: When you change the width of a table column, other column must adapt the available space. this is how html tables works.

Comment: Kindly check here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495634/how-to-make-a-table-with-equal-column-widths-in-css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a table with equal column widths in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495634/how-to-make-a-table-with-equal-column-widths-in-css)

Comment: @minaalfy Please read the question properly, I am referring for a specific row.

Comment: @BearNithi Is there other way to achieve that?

Comment: You can set `table-layout: fixed;` on your table. so you can prevent the default behavour of browser

Comment: @BearNithi I already try that but the text overflow to right.

Comment: use `word-wrap: break-word;`

Comment: @BearNithi unfortunately I cant do that because the text should not break base on the design. It should stay inline.

Comment: @kirito127 it should stay in a single line? If so, and if you want *only one row to have variable column widths* you should not be using table layout

Comment: @kukkuz I think you're right, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML table behavior is fixed and very difficult to manipulate. You can read more about this [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/277778/why-are-people-making-tables-with-divs). This is why most people do NOT use `table` tags to create a table, but instead make something called a div table - a table made out of `div` tags. You can do what you are wanting using a `div` table like this:

```css
.div-table {
    display: table;
    width: 300px;
}
.div-table-row {
    display: table-row;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.div-table-row:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: white;
}
.div-table-col {
    float: left;
    display: table-column;
}
.div-table-col:nth-child(odd) {
    width: 20%;
}
.div-table-col:nth-child(even) {
    width: 80%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-table">
  <div class="div-table-row">
    <div class="div-table-col">Share Series</div>
    <div class="div-table-col">VEON ADS (NASD)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="div-table-row">
    <div class="div-table-col">Time</div>
    <div class="div-table-col">02/27/2019 16:00 (GMT-05:00)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="div-table-row">
    <div class="div-table-col">Currency</div>
    <div class="div-table-col">USD</div>
  </div>
  <div class="div-table-row">
    <div class="div-table-col">Market</div>
    <div class="div-table-col">NASDAQ</div>
  </div>
  <div class="div-table-row">
    <div class="div-table-col">ISIN</div>
    <div class="div-table-col">US91822M1062</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good answer but I already solved it. I added the solution below my question. Thank you.