# Equal columns on table

Tags: html, css

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/mVX93/19/

```
#my-table{width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;} /*or whatever width you want*/
#my-table td{width:2000px;padding:4px;border:1px solid #000;vertical-align:top;} /*something big or 100%*/
```

I'm trying to make it so no matter how many columns there are, each one is an equal width. However, this approach *should* work but it doesn,t we can see one is clearly bigger because it has bigger content.

Can this be done, without having to specify specific CSS for the number of columns?

Comment: Did you try setting `table-layout:fixed` on the table?

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to use table. cs I found one more way to do it where your contents will not flow out.. Check the below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375288/make-columns-of-equal-width-in-table

Comment: It doesnt have to be a table, but the more compatibility the better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `table-layout:fixed` on the table, and remove fixed width you have set on `td`.

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/mVX93/24/)**

```
#my-table{
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed
}

#my-table td{
    padding:4px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: That's a good solution, but is there anyway to stop the text going into the next cell for example

Comment: something like this might be good, shame it is css3 only though http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/mVX93/25/

Comment: I updated the fiddle - the overflowing text was caused by the dots not having a space between them making it a really wide word - which doesn't usually happen (except maybe for long urls)

Comment: @Kunsang per my answer

Answer (score 2):

Simply use:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/mVX93/31/)

```
#my-table{
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed
}

#my-table td{
    padding:4px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    vertical-align:top;
    word-break:break-word; /* <-- ensure the line of dots can be broken */
}
```

[**More on `word-break` from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

> The word-break CSS property is used to specify how (or if) to break
>   lines within words.

[**You may also want to add `word-wrap:break-word;`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap)

> The word-wrap CSS property is used to specify whether or not the
>   browser may break lines within words in order to prevent overflow (in
>   other words, force wrapping) when an otherwise unbreakable string is
>   too long to fit in its containing box.