# Same width cells in table column?

Tags: html, css

I have read the following:

-autoformatting-1. [HTML table: keep the same width for columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570154/html-table-keep-the-same-width-for-columns)

-autoformatting-1. "If you set the style table-layout: fixed; on your table, you can override the browser's automatic column resizing. The browser will then set column widths based on the width of cells in the first row of the table." - This doesn't work in Firefox 66.0.4 and never has for me. Check out https://jsfiddle.net/x342vchn/ :

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.narrow {
  max-width: 20px; /* Without this, the first table doesn't work either! */
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="narrow">sdkajdwaudawjdjawhdwjahdawjdhajh</td>
      <td>hi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>hi</td>
      <td>hi</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="narrow">hi</td>
      <td>hi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sdkajdwaudawjdjawhdwjahdawjdhajh</td>
      <td>hi</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The first table "works" because the wide content is in the cell that has the max-width restriction. The second table ignores everything.

-autoformatting-2. [Set the table column width constant regardless of the amount of text in its cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457506/set-the-table-column-width-constant-regardless-of-the-amount-of-text-in-its-cell)

-autoformatting-2. In this case, the answer suggests setting the same width on all cells.

If I want to set the same height for cells in a row, I can target them with a class on the row. So how do I set the same *fixed* width on cells in a column without specifically setting the max-width and width of all affected cells?

I have done some web searching, and blogs suggest the same as the first answer, but it **does not** work.

I have also tried setting the width of the first cell (th) in a thead. That made no difference either.

Am I missing something or is Firefox broken?

Currently, I'm using the same class on all cells of a certain width, even if they are empty because the contents can be modified with JS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a col/colgroup approach (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col) and setting the width attribute?

You'd have something similar to this:

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <col width="40px" />
        <col width="20px" />
        <tr>
            <td>hi</td>
            <td>hi</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>hi</td>
            <td>hi</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I think this is the way to go for your case.

Comment: No, I have not.. but I just did now: the overflow-wrap doesn't work and max-width is ignored. :( Thanks for teaching me about *col* though.